# Riemann Zeta Function-like Integral with Generalized Lower Bound

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

During my studies, I've encountered the following integral where $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$

> $$\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{x}-1} dx$$

I know if $a=0$, this evaluates to $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})\zeta(\frac{3}{2})$, but I'm not sure how to handle the generalized lower bound.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall assume $a>0$.

Write
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{x}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \sqrt{x}\,  e^{-(n+1) x}$$
$$\int_a^\infty \sqrt{x}\,  e^{-(n+1) x}\,dx=\sqrt{a}\,\,\frac{ e^{-a (n+1)}}{n+1}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\frac{\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{a (n+1)}\right)}{(n+1)^{3/2}}$$

$$\color{red}{\int_a^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{x}-1}= \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\sqrt{a} \log
   \left(1-e^{-a}\right)-}$$ $$\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a (n+1)}\right)}{(n+1)^{3/2}}}$$